# DynamoDBScanExpression withLimit returns more records than Limit

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Have to list all the records from a DynamoDB table, without any filter expression.
I want to limit the number of records hence using DynamoDBScanExpression with setLimit.

```
DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
....
// Set ExclusiveStartKey
....
scanExpression.setLimit(10);
```

However, the scan operation returns more than 10 results always !!!!
Is this the expected behaviour and if so how?

Comment: How are you loading/getting the results?

Comment: Got it, I was using mapper.scan which is returning paginated list and size() operation makes internal calls to get all the records.                                               Should have been using mapper.scanPage() instead !

Answer (score 0):

**`Python Answer`**

It is not possible to set a `limit` for `scan()` operations, however, it is possible to do so with a `query`.

A `query` searches through `items`, the rows in the database. It starts at the top or bottom of the list and finds items based on set criteria. **You must have a partion and a sort key to do this.**

A scan on the other hand searches through the **ENTIRE** database and not by items, and, as a result, is **NOT** ordered.

Since queries are based on items and scan is based on the **ENTIRE** database, only queries can support limits.

To answer OP's question, essentially it doesn't work because you're using `scan` not `query`.

**Here is an example of how to use it using CLIENT syntax.** (More advanced syntax version. Sorry I don't have a simpler example that uses `resource`. you can google that.)

```py
    def retrieve_latest_item(self):
        result = self.dynamodb_client.query(
        TableName="cleaning_company_employees",
        KeyConditionExpression= "works_night_shift = :value",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':value': {"BOOL":"True"}},
        ScanIndexForward = False,
        Limit = 3
        )
    return result
```

Here is the [DynamoDB module docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html)