# Why does DynamoDB limit not working with scan?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, limit

I'm running the following code:

```
DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
scanExpression.setLimit(100);
PaginatedScanList<T> list = dynamoDBMapper.scan(clazz, scanExpression);
```

When checking the list's size, I get **40,000** instead of **100**.

Also, when iterating over the list, I get all the 40k item instead of just the 100.

Why isn't the limit working?

Using java client SDK version `1.10.77`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899150/dynamodbscanexpression-withlimit-returns-more-records-than-limit

Comment: From the below source, it seems that the limit used to control the batch size and not limit the entire result.
https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

Here's the implementation of the `size()` method `PaginatedList<T>` in the AWS Java SDK, which `PaginatedScanList<T>` extends:

```
  @Override
public int size() {
    loadAllResults();
    return allResults.size();
}
```

When you call `size()`, you're telling the SDK to fetch all the results of your scan, not checking the size of the current page.